# Tagging for Adventure

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was looking around and realized we are inconsistent on what we call adventures - we have [modules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules), [adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventures), [published-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventures) and [scenario-authoring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scenario-authoring). That's a bit of a mess; obviously the last two have some slight distinction (the authoring a bit more than the published - I would say when people say "module" they by definition mean a published adventure).  Even [adventure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) isn't a real good tag, it looks like it's 50% used for published adventures and 50% for more of a synonym with scenario-authoring.

The tags [campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign) and [adventure-path](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-path) are also closely related to this discussion.

So what term should we use as canonical?

Comment: I have implemented the suggestion below, and will work on preening "adventure" questions over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose that of the three equivalent terms - module, adventure, scenario - we use adventure.  Scenario is more technically correct but it's also not what the average Joe searches for. I think adventure is more accessible (as is proven by scenario's use in only one of these tags with 13 occurrences, as opposed to module with 14 and adventure with 73).

We would then have:

1. [published-adventure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-adventure) synonyms: published-adventures, modules,
   published-scenarios
2. [adventure-writing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-writing) synonyms: scenario-authoring, adventure-design

We could then preen the [adventure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) questions to put them into the right category... Those have some bad overlap with [campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign) as well, cf. [Any good premade campaigns for beginners?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/any-good-premade-campaigns-for-beginners). Once all 40 questions are disposed of, synonym adventure to adventure-writing. A pure adventure (or module, or scenario) tag is so vague as to be unhelpful, since it cam be used to describe everything PCs do in play and most of what GMs do in prep for play.

There is also [adventure-path](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-path) which is an interesting case - given that there is a question [What is an Adventure Path?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/what-is-an-adventure-path) I guess there is a niche in there right between published-adventures and campaign but it's narrow - I'd leave this be for right now but keep an eye on it.